# Conditionally return object with Locator.CurrentMutable.Register, based on configuration?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have an application where I would like to load/save attachments from either the file system or Amazon S3 - depending on whether it's running in the cloud or on a local desktop PC.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
public class AppBootstrapper
{
    public bool Cloud { get; set; }

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Cloud = false;

        RegisterDependencies();
    }

    public void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        Locator.CurrentMutable.Register( () => {
            if ( Cloud ) return new AmazonS3Repo();

            return new FileRepo() as IAttachmentRepo;
        }, typeof(IAttachmentRepo) );
    }
}
```

Which, of course, means that you'd have to make `AppBootstrapper` a singleton (in order to set the `Cloud` property) and the benefit of Dependency Inversion is lost. It would be nice if I could do this:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register<bool>( cloud => {
    if ( cloud ) return new AmazonS3Repo();

    return new FileRepo() as IAttachmentRepo;
})
```

However, I guess what I'm talking about is Dependency Injection (and it's not what `Splat` is designed to do). Is there another way to do this using `Splat`?

Comment: I’m putting this as a comment first to make sure it fits your needs. Have you tried using the contract parameter of Register?
Register(() => new AmazonS3Repo(), “AmazonS3”, typeof(IAttachmentRepo))
and
Register(() => new FileRepo(), “FileRepo”, typeof(IAttachmentRepo))
Then
Locator.Current.GetService(typeof(IAttachmentRepo), "AmazonS3")

Comment: No!? Are you saying I could do this - `Locator.Current.GetService<IAttachmentRepo>( cloud ? "AmazonS3" : "FileSystem")`?

Comment: Yep, check it out: [ServiceLocation](https://github.com/reactiveui/splat/blob/develop/src/Splat/ServiceLocation.cs)

Comment: Cool. This looks like the kind of thing I was after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to use the *contract* parameter of *Register* and *GetService*.

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new AmazonS3Repo(), “AmazonS3”, typeof(IAttachmentRepo));
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new FileRepo(), “FileRepo”, typeof(IAttachmentRepo));
```

Then later

```
var service = Locator.Current.GetService(typeof(IAttachmentRepo), cloud ? "AmazonS3" : "FileSystem");
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I think I'll end up creating a service that stores settings so I can make this call. But the `contract` parameter allows this to be possible (without using a Singleton)

Comment: Okay, cool. Glad to hear it got you headed in the right direction.